# Deleting from Firebase, notifyDataSetChanged(); doesn't refresh ListView

Tags: android

Basically after deleting Object from Firebase, `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not update it in realtime. I tried to remove object from adapter itself but it also fails.

Coming back to this fragment shows updated list but i think it's because of child added. Here's my code.

```
public class ArchiveFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ArchiveFragment newInstance(Beer beer) {
        ArchiveFragment archiveFragment = new ArchiveFragment();
        if (beer != null) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("beer", beer);
            archiveFragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        return archiveFragment;
    }

    public ArchiveFragment(){}

    private ArrayList<Beer> beerDB = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView beerList;
    private RecyclerView beerRec;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.archive_fragment, container, false);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        beerList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.beerList);
        final ArrayAdapter<Beer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Beer>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,beerDB);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("BeerList");
        beerList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        beerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Object deletedBeer = beerList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Beer delBeer = (Beer) deletedBeer;
                deleteBeer(delBeer.getKey());
            }
        });

        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Beer value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Beer.class);
                value.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                beerDB.add(value);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                beerDB.remove(key);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void deleteBeer(String key){
        mDatabase.child(key).removeValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're removing the item from your `ArrayList` using the `remove` function which is incorrect. The `remove` function takes the index of the item in your `ArrayList` which needs to be removed. But here, when you get the key from the `dataSnapshot` it doesn't match any index of your `ArrayList` and hence the item is not actually removed from your `ArrayList`. So you need to change your `onChildRemoved` function like this.

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

    for (int i = 0; i < beerDB.size(); i++) {
        // Find the item to remove and then remove it by index
        if (beerDB.get(i).key.equals(key)) {
            beerDB.remove(i);
            break;
        } 
    }

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: It's working now! Thank you very much, i was fighting with this for couple hours. :)

Comment: Glad to know that helped.